# Three squares and three circles packed into a right triangle

Tags: geometry

If we have three squares and three circles inside a right triangle if the radius of the small circle is $19$ and  the radius of the big circle is $99$.How to find the radius of the medium circle 
[image: diagram shows a right triangle partitioned into three squares and 7 small right triangles, with circles inscribed in three of the small right triangles]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every triangle you see is similar, and the circles are in proportion to the triangles that they are in the corner of.  The relation between the triangles of the small and middle circles (triangle flipped over and filled with a square) is the same as the middle to the large.  So if $r$ is the radius of the middle circle we have $\frac r{19}=\frac {99}r$ or $r=\sqrt {19 \cdot 99}$